# How do I swap TableAdapter DataViews?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I want a user to have different "views" of a TableAdapter. These do not need to be committed back to the database.

I have tried something like the following
      mytba.DataView = someOtherDataView;
with no success.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new **DataView** from the underlying **DataTable**.

It's been a while since I used TableAdapters, [but you can fill a data table with it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MyTableAdapter.Fill(dt);
DataView dv1 = new DataView(dt);
DataView dv2 = new DataView(dt);
```